# If $(a-1),a,(a+1)$ are consecutive positive integers, $ (a+1)^3 \neq a^3 + (a-1)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, proof-verification

I had to prove the following statement:

> If $(a-1),a,(a+1)$ are consecutive positive integers, $(a+1)^3 \neq a^3 + (a-1)^3$

My attempt at the solution was to first expand each side to get 
$$a^3 + 3a^2 + 3a + 1 \neq 2a^3 - 3a^2 +3a - 1\\
      0 \neq a^3 - 6a^2 - 2$$

However, $a^3 - 6a^2 - 2$ does hit the $x$-axis at $a = 6.0546$.

> *Does that mean that the statement is incorrect?*

Comment: Is $6.0546$ a positive integer? You need to show that the polynomial you have is irreducible over the integers. You may do this by applying Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: $6.0546...$ is not an integer, thus since you have calculated it to be the solution, then the solution is not an integer and thus the statement i supported, not refuted. Since it is a cubic, there can be up to three roots, though, you should show that there are no linear factors over the integers, not just this one.

Comment: wait so since the only time it ever hits the x-axis is on that one point which is not an integer (something i can't believe i missed), i can just leave it at that? and say that it's true?

Comment: A cubic equation *can* have up to three real roots. If you demonstrated three roots, none of which are integers, then you'd be done. This equation has only one real root though, so you'd have to show that the other two are not real and therefore not integers.

Comment: @user you could say that, but that is applying analysis to an algebraic problem, which is a bit sloppy.

Comment: Your expansion of the RHS has an error. The term "$+3a^2$" should be "$-3a^2$". **EDIT:** Ah, but I see you used it correctly when you combined terms in the next line. So just a single character typo.

Comment: I corrected the typo.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Last_Theorem

Comment: @LordSoth I wonder how OP's teacher/professor would react if he cited that as the answer.

Comment: @user92774 Imagine him asking for a proof of the theorem.

Comment: It's quite elementary, but... you know, too large for the margin and all.

Comment: @IanColey, a cubic polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ if it has no integer roots. The rational root criterion tells that candidates are $\pm 1$, $\pm 2$. None works, and it is irreducible.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $n^3-6n^2 = 2$ for some integer $n$. It is easy to check that $n$ cannot be odd. Hence $n = 2k$ for some integer $k$. We have $8k^3-24k^2 = 2$, or equivalently, $k^3-3k^2 = \frac{1}{4}$, which is a contradiction since $k$ was supposed to be an integer.

Comment: sorry could you explain why n cannot be odd?

Comment: @user125535  $n$ cannot be odd, as if $n$ is odd, then $n^3$ is odd, and $6n^2$ is even. If you subtract an even number from an odd number, you get an odd number, but the number $2$ is an even number.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is show that the equation $a^3-6a^2-2=0$ has no positive integer solution.  If it did, then you'd have $a^2(a-6)=2$.  But $a^2\mid2$ implies $a=1$, in which case $a^2(a-6)=-5\not=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the shortest or the greatest argument, but it may be helpful to the OP. Let $f(a) = a^3-6a^2-2$. We take the derivative to obtain $f'(a) = 3a^2-12a$. The roots of the derivative are $0$ and $4$. Looking at the sign of the derivative, we observe that $f$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0)$, decreasing on $[0,4)$, and again increasing on $[4,\infty)$. Since $f(0) = -2$, and $f$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0)$, we know there cannot be any roots that are less or equal to $0$. Now, we also know $f$ is decreasing on $[0,4]$ so there can be roots in this interval either. Now we know that the only root is (if it exists) greater than or equal to $4$. Again the fact that $f$ is decreasing on $[0,4]$ shows that $f(4)<0$ (without calculation). Since $f$ grows to infinity as its argument grows to infinity, there is thus one real root greater than $4$. We now observe $f(6) = -2$ and $f(7)>0$. Hence the one real root is in the interval $(6,7)$ which contains no integers.

Answer (score 0):

$a^3−6a^2−2$ does hit the $x$-axis at $a=6.0546$, so, after placing the value of $a$ in the equation, you get the value of $a^3−6a^2−2$ to be $0.001536$ which is not equal to $0$.